# Appending debug header in custom malloc

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, void-pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I'm pretty rust at my C still and I am just not figuring this out. What I am trying to do is to implement my own malloc so I can keep track of allocations and debug missing calls to free(). I have a header like this:

```
typedef struct MemoryInfo {
  mem_Kind kind;
  unsigned int id;
  struct MemoryInfo* prev;
  struct MemoryInfo* next;
} MemoryInfo;
```

And my custom malloc looks something like this:

```
void* my_malloc(mem_Kind kind, unsigned int size) {
  MemoryInfo* mem;

  allocCount++;
  mem = (MemoryInfo*)malloc(sizeof(MemoryInfo) + size);
  mem->id = id;
  mem->kind = kind;
  // set prev/next...

  return mem + sizeof(MemoryInfo); // return pointer to memory after header
}
```

But I'm clearly getting my pointer arithmetic wrong because it blows up pretty horribly very quickly. However if I add a `void* memory` to the end of my struct and do another malloc then it seems to do fine, the problem with that is that I can't really find the header in `my_free` if I do that. I'm trying to basically prepend the header so I can do some reverse pointer arithmetic to get the header in free.

```
void my_free(void* memory) {
  MemoryInfo* mem = memory - sizeof(MemoryInfo); // not correct either
  allocCount--;
  free(mem);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a problem with adding to pointer. It has to be like this:

```
return (char*)mem + sizeof(MemoryInfo); // return pointer to memory after header
```

and

```
void my_free(void* memory) {
  MemoryInfo* mem = (MemoryInfo*)((char*)memory - sizeof(MemoryInfo)); // not correct either
  allocCount--;
  free(mem);
}
```

By the way. Look at this program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct MemoryInfo {
  int kind;
  unsigned int id;
  struct MemoryInfo* prev;
  struct MemoryInfo* next;
} MemoryInfo;



int main()
{
  MemoryInfo* ptr = 0;

  printf("sizeof: %d\n",sizeof(MemoryInfo));
  printf("%d\n",ptr+3);
  return 0;
}
```

I have added 3 to pointer to MemoryInfo, but its value become 3*sizeof(MemoryInfo).

Comment: Interesting. Works like a charm! Can you explain why void* doesn't work and I have to cast it to char*?

Answer (score 0):

Your pointer arithmetic is wrong. in `ptr+1` the +1 already uses the correct increment (sizeof *ptr). You would have to increment by `sizeof *ptr` if ptr were a char pointer, but it is not.

```
void *my_malloc(mem_Kind kind, unsigned int size) {
  MemoryInfo  mem;

  allocCount++;
  mem = malloc(sizeof *mem + size);
  mem->id = id;
  mem->kind = kind;
  // set prev/next...

  return mem + 1; // return pointer to memory after header
}


void my_free(void *memory) {
  MemoryInfo *mem = memory; // not correct either
  mem -= 1;
  allocCount--;
  free(mem);
}
```

Also, please take into consideration that malloc() and friends should return a pointer that is suitable to every object, and has to be aligned to the *natural* boundary for any object. (this could be 32 bits, 64 bits, or anything that your platform dictates)
Your sizes could fail for sizeof (int)==2 and sizeof (void*) == 8 , for instance. (but which seems a very rare case, luckily)

Answer (score 0):

good practice is define like this:

```
struct some_struct {
  size_t data_size;
  struct some_struct  *next, *prev;
  void * struct_data[];
}
```

and us it like that:

```
struct some_struct *get_some_struct ( void *buf,size_t buflen,struct some_struct **next){
  *next=0;
  struct some_struct *s=(struct some_struct *)buf;
  if ( s && buflen < sizof(*s) + s->data_size )
    *next = (char*)s + s->data_size;
    return s;
  else
    return 0;
}
```

So, if you need to iterate through structures, you can get properly the offset of next structure in buffer. I just want you to get the approach.
Will be pleased if you'll get it